# Return result from JOIN table once

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following join table is used to load a list of outstanding work orders for a specific user (in this example case we set this to user ID 1). When the user clicks on this record they will be taken to the full works order detail, with all the different tasks set to them (WorksOrderStage). As this new window will contain all of the tasks they are required to do for this order, I only want the front page to show that they have a task they need to complete. Thus will only need to show the order once, as opposed to several times.

```
SELECT wo.ID, wo.WONumber, wo.Item, wo.Quantity, wo.Status, wo.DateCreated, ws.Assignee, wo.Priority, ws.Complete
FROM WorksOrder AS wo 
LEFT JOIN WorksOrderStage AS ws ON wo.ID = ws.WorksOrderId
WHERE ws.Assignee = 1 AND ws.Complete IS NULL
```

If the above statement is run, and say the user has 4 tasks assigned to 1 works order, this will show 4 rows, where I only want to show 1. I have tried to add a group by clause onto the wo.ID however this fails and does not allow me to excecute the statement correctly. How can I achieve only returning 1 row per works order?

[image]

Edit: I added a quick example with test data using MS Access, In the top table these are the results returned using the above statement. As you can see, Work Order WO0002 is returned twice, due to user 1 having 2 tasks/stages assigned to them. However I would only like this to be returned once as shown in the bottom example.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and explain how to choose which of the four to show.

Comment: I am using SQL Server for this and the GUI is done using WPF C#. I only wish to return a result if the tasks are not completed hence the ws.Complete IS NULL. So the returned stage returned doesnt really matter as the user will see the actual outstanding stages/tasks when they open the works order detail window

Comment: Before you can define How to do something you need to ***unambiguously*** define What you want to do.  Create some dummy example data to demonstrate the inputs, then show what output you want for those given inputs.  This explains why you should go to that effort : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your left join to WorksOrderStage is implicitly converted to an inner join because you refer to `ws.Assignee = 1`. But if you only want to show one row and none of the actual columns from ws have anything meaningful or unique (among the related rows), then add `TOP 1` to the query. The absence of an ORDER BY clause will not make a difference (though it usually does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you want I assume:

```
SELECT wo.ID, wo.WONumber, wo.Item, wo.Quantity, wo.Status, wo.DateCreated, wo.Priority
FROM WorksOrder AS wo
WHERE exists (
   select 1 from WorksOrderStage AS ws 
   where wo.ID = ws.WorksOrderId
   and ws.Assignee = 1 
   AND ws.Complete IS NULL
)
```

I removed ws.assignee from select because it would be always 1  , or ws.complete will be always null

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, I apologize if my explanation wasn't clear. I will accept as the answer once the cooldown time has ended. Thank you all for your help.